# Remote Debugging Chrome on Android issue

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I am have issues using the remote debugging feature of the Chrome Developers tools with my Android device (LG Nitro running Android version 4.0.4). It was working perfectly several days ago but now my device never appears on the about:inspect page.

I have followed and carefully considered [these instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) including the troubleshooting tips. I have also searched for the answer to my problem but have not been able to find anything that works.

I am using Chrome version 35.0.1916.141 on my Android device and version 35.0.1916.114 on my PC (Windows 7). Neither says any updates are available.

Please note:

- I have enabled debugging on my Android device and the small bug icon appears in the menu bar at the top of the screen when the USB cable is connected.
- I have installed the necessary drivers for my phone on my PC.
- Chrome is open on both devices
- "Discover USB devices" is checked
- I have tried restarting both the computer and my phone several times

The only thing I have changed on my computer since the last time it was working was to download 64-bit Java. Could this have any effect? If anyone has any input or ideas, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you may have gotten lucky.  Next time this happens, try this:

1) Unplug your device.

2) Revoke USB debugging in the Developer Tools.

3) In the command line:

adb kill-server

adb start-server

Plug in device and accept fingerprint.

Voila, it appears in Chrome again.   I went through a lot of pain with random problems with my Galaxy S5 not showing up, I was pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Also note that you can try skipping the Revocation steps for a quick and dirty solution.  I find that occasionally my laptop will crash and after the crash, remote debugging no longer works.  Simply killing and restarting the server is enough, no revoking necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After launching my Android application from Eclipse on my device, it suddenly showed up on the about:inspect page. I am not sure why it was not recognizing my phone before but it seems to be working now.