# Remote Debugging Chrome on Android issue Galaxy S5 Neo/New - No devices detected

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging, samsung-mobile

I try to connect my Galaxy S5 New/Neo to my PC for remote debugging.

[Screenshot - remote debugging console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTZol.jpg)

**Config :**
- Android 5.1
- Windows 7
- Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m + chromium + chrome canary
- S5 Drivers up to date

I follow the tips here : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

and also see this post : [Remote Debugging Chrome on Android issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126519/remote-debugging-chrome-on-android-issue)

- I have enabled debugging on my Android device
- I have installed the necessary drivers for my phone on my PC.
- Chrome is open on both devices
- "Discover USB devices" is checked
- I have tried restarting both the computer and my phone several times

**and my S5 still not be detected by chrome dev tools.**

If anyone can help me, it will be appreciated !

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED :

I fixed it !

[Screenshot - Android studio updated lines to fix the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbnUt.jpg)

First i download Android Studio, and then i update these lines with the phone connected :

Next on my Galaxy S5 New/Neo i have a message with a fingerprint for debugging mode, i click accept.

And then just connect to the chrome dev tools and the device is now detected !

I hope my searchs and explications will help somebody next!

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you want to debug mobile chrome on your pc chrome then now try to got to `chrome://inspect`.

- open new tab in chrome browser
- add `chrome://inspect` in url
- you will see mobile chrome listed there
- click `inspect`

See if this helps

Comment: Thank you,I know how to open the dev console... but no devices are detected, that's why i asked this question.